# Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be elements of a transitive set $A$, if $x\in y \wedge y\in z$ then can we conclude that $x\in z$ or $x\notin z$?

Tags: set-theory

Given $A$ is a transitive set and $x, y, z$ are elements of $A$ such that $x\in y \wedge y\in z$. Can we conclude that $x\in z$?

For the transitive set $\{0, 1,..., n\}$, I can see that it's true (with $0=\emptyset;1=0^{+};2=1^{+}, ...$). However, I can't prove that it's true or false for any arbitrary transitive set.

Comment: The title asks a trivial question. The post asks something different.

Comment: Isn't $A=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ a counterexample?

Comment: As Greg Martin points out, your claim is not true. A transitive set with the property you describe is sometimes called hereditarily transitive. 

A hereditarily transitive set is just an ordinal.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName, did you mean my claim that the transitive set $\{0, 1,...,n\}$ satisfies the property mentioned is not true? Note that this set is not the same as the one in the counter example Greg Martin has provided.

Comment: @TranKhanh They say it is true for ordinals, so wouldn’t be saying your example (an ordinal) is wrong.

Comment: @TranKhanh some times the definition of an ordinal is just a hereditarily transitive set. 

I think your example is correct since the set $\{0,1,\dots, n\}$ is just the ordinal $n+1$.

Comment: It's not true in General. Let A be a  transitive set containing at least two elements.Let a∈A, and a be nonempty. Then by foundation {a} is not transitive, but A ∪ {{a}} is a transitive set. So, given any transitive set with cardinality at least 2, we can always build a non hereditary transitive set. Note: If all you know is that a set is transitive, you can't make any conclusions about if its elements are transitive. You need more information

Comment: By foundation, all transitive sets contain the empty set- and so the closest you could get to the claim, is saying that all transitive sets contain at least one transitive element. But, you cannot say anything more.